# Do webjobs get redistributed on adding new VMs due to autoscaling?

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk, azure-webjobs-continuous

There are 5 webjobs running on 2 VMs. 3rd VM is added after sometime because of auto scaling. Are the webjobs redistributed across VMs? If webjobs are not redistributed what is the point of adding another VM if it will remain idle?

Answer (score 0):

@vignesh, By default, WebJobs scale with their associated Azure Web Apps instance.
If a continuous job is set as singleton (set to =true), it'll run only on a single instance opposed to running on all instances.

On an App Service Plan (ASP), when the app runs, it runs on all the VM instances configured in the ASP. If multiple apps are in the same App Service plan, they all share the same VM instances. If you have multiple deployment slots for an app, all deployment slots also run on the same VM instances. If you enable diagnostic logs, perform backups, or **run WebJobs**, they also use CPU cycles and memory on these VM instances. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/overview-hosting-plans?source=recommendations#how-does-my-app-run-and-scale) doc.

I noticed you'd a [related question](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1085376/index.html) on Microsoft Q&A.